# Django insert into DB works, but psql cli doesn't seem to show it

Tags: django, postgresql, debugging, orm

I'm writing tests for a Django web app. And in my `setupTestData` class method i'm manually creating some user like below

`cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(cls.username, email=cls.email, password=cls.password, first_name=cls.first_name, last_name=cls.last_name)`

The call above goes without failing. But the record doesnt seem to exist at all in DB.

How I'm able to confirm this is in the real test methods, the API's fail because the User doesn't seem to exist in DB.

I however crossed checked this. By using

```
import pdb

# I use this after the .create_user() line to stop execution
# and use psql cli to inspect the test DB but i can't see the inserted row
pdb.set_trace()
```

Inside pdb, i use the following to debug if Django ORM has saved the record.

```
(Pdb) display cls.user.pk
display cls.user.pk: 1
```

Meaning the insertion as been given an id 1.

But running `select count(*) from Authorization_users` in psql gives 0 rows.

I need help in debugging this further. Thanks

Comment: Probably due to transaction isolation. Does it appear once the view has completed?

Comment: Oh wow, I haven't tested that case scenario but when I test the API it returns successfully. Let me check it out.

Comment: API works, tested through postman. I can see the registered user in the DB. But i can't see it in the test DB when i stop it through pdb.

Comment: So it turns out as you mentioned transaction isolation, when i input the transaction isolation level of the DB in settings.py it works out fine no matter the isolation level. But the moment i don't specify it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Any help here please?

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can help.